# JS Button active only if checkbox is True

Tags: javascript, detail-page

I would like to create a Detail Page JS button with the below (under the Lead object if it matters)

If A=TRUE and the button is pressed, update checkbox B to TRUE.
If A=FALSE and the button is pressed, show Alert "Not the Right Case"

Really straight forward yet am having issues implementing.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
var newRecords = []; 
var c = new sforce.SObject("Lead"); 
c.id ="{!Lead.Id}"; 


if ({!Lead.RedCarpetSignup__c}= true) 
{ 
c.{!Lead.Email_Verified_and_Activated__c} = true;
}


newRecords.push(c); 
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords); 
window.location.reload();
```

Thanks.

Comment: how can members help you without seeing your code?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the following strategy

`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
if({! !your_Object_api_name__c.your_checkbox_api_name__c}){ 
alert('your custom message'); 
} 
else{
//update checkbox B to TRUE
}`

Answer (score 0):

Solution will be like this

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Case"); 
var CustomFieldValue = "{!Case.CustomField__c}"; 


if(CustomFieldValue==false) 
{ 
    alert("Not the Right Case"); 
}
else
{ 
    caseObj.CustomCheckbox__c = true;
    var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]);     
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: I used the below yet the checkbox is not turning on:

`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js")} 
var caseObj = new sforce.SObject("Lead"); 
var CustomFieldValue = "{!Lead.A}"; 


if(CustomFieldValue==false) 
{ 
alert("Not the Right Case"); 
} 
else 
{ 
caseObj.B = true; 
var result = sforce.connection.update([caseObj]); 
location.reload(); 
}`

Any idea?